# ¿Como denegar usuarios para que no puedan entrar por url?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, webforms

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema ya que no encuentro la manera de como resolverlo cualquier ayuda es bien recibida y muchas gracias por anticipado.

Tengo una aplicación en asp.net con c# webForms, esta aplicación utiliza autenticacion de windows (es decir utilizando las credenciales del computador cliente o usuario) y no tienen ningún formulario de login.

Solo tengo dos tablas como se muestra en la imagen y no quiero escribir todos los usuarios en el webconfig sino que sea un poco mas dinámico.

La segunda tabla la utilizo para hacer un menú dinámico como en el articulo del link y eso me funciona perfecto solo me falta la denegación de los usuarios.
https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/108804/Database-Driven-N-Level-MultiLevel-BootstrapResponsive-Vertical-Menu-using-C-and-jQuery-in-ASPNet/

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Como puedo denegar a los usuarios para que no puedan entrar por url a un formulario que no les corresponde teniendo en cuenta que no existe un formulario de login?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código en el webconfi

```
// configuraciones web config

<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Comment: podrias hacerlo usando Directory Services y Active Directory para obtener los datos del usuario logueado

Answer (score 0):

Veamos a ver si se entiende, primero obtienes los datos del usuario logeado y creas una tabla en tu base de datos con los usuario que quieres que no tengan acceso, como te puse en el comentario...

Es necesario este Using, es necesario que lo agregues a la carpeta References de tu proyecto:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
```

crea una clase llamada ADUser:

```
public class ADUser
{
    public String FirstName;
    public String LastName;
    public String DisplayName;
    public String UserName;
    public String DistinguishedName;
    public String Name;
}
```

Crea otra clase llamada ADInfo:
crea un procedimiento el cual nos retornara los datos del usuario, es necesario que te sepas la direccion LDAP de tu empresa, o si puedes obtenerla por default.

```
public ADUser GetUserInfo(String UserName)
    {
        ADUser SingleUser = new ADUser();
        List<ADUser> ADList = new List<ADUser>();

        if (UserName == null)
            return SingleUser;

        DirectoryEntry enTry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + UserName.Split('\\')[0] + ".tuempresa.com");//o puedes llamar el procedimiento por default GetCurrentDomainPath()
        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(enTry);
        mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + UserName.Split('\\')[1] + "))";

        SearchResult resEnt = mySearcher.FindOne();
        object firstName = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value;
        SingleUser.FirstName = firstName != null ? firstName.ToString() : "";
        object lastName = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["SN"].Value;
        SingleUser.LastName = lastName != null ? lastName.ToString() : "";
        SingleUser.DisplayName = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();
        SingleUser.DistinguishedName = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
        SingleUser.Name = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
        SingleUser.UserName = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();
        ADList.Add(SingleUser);
        return SingleUser;
    }
```

*Si no tienes la direccion LDAP puedes usar este procedimiento para obtenerlo por defaul

```
private string GetCurrentDomainPath()
{
DirectoryEntry de =
 new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");

return "LDAP://" +
 de.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0].
     ToString();
}
```

invoca a tu clase en el formuario que no quieras que tengan acceso:

```
ADUser user = new ADInfo().GetUserInfo(User.Identity.Name);
```

aqui meadiante la variabe **user** puedes hacer:

```
strin userlogueado = user.UserName;\\resultado perezjuanito
```

Con la variable puedes hacer un simple query a tu tabla **UsuariosSinAccesso** por ejemplo y si develve true, que no les de acceso.

Listo espero tus comentarios.

Comment: Hola @Manny perdon por la demora en responder y gracias por tomar la molestia en ayudar. En cuanto a la respuesta todos mis usuarios los tengo en la base de datos en esas dos tablas que te muestro. No existe un LDAP en la empresa de donda pueda tomar los datos, Solo tengo esas dos tablas y con ellas quiero denegar a los usuarios, Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera pero tengo problemas en el redireccionamiento aquí postule una nueva pregunta con este problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285400/problema-al-direccionamiento-de-la-pagina-establecida-como-inicio-desde-la-máste