# Problema al direccionamiento de la pagina establecida como inicio desde la máster page

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola a todos espero me puedan ayudar ya que no entiendo porque me hace un ciclo infinito al tratar de rediccionar a mi pagina establecida como inicio en **`Visual Studio 2008`** de antemano gracias.

Tengo una pagina llamada `Default.aspx` esta pagina la puse como **Establecer como pagina de inicio** en **`Visual Studio 2008`**, por lo que se ejecuta cuando inicio la aplicación.

Posteriormente en mi `master page` hago una consulta a mi procedimiento y si la pagina es diferente entonces la redirecciono a `Default.aspx` pero esta pagina no me la muestra, al llegar al **`if`** no termina y vuelve hacia arriba a ejecutar el código como si fuese un ciclo infinito.

Todo esto lo hago para denegar a mis usuarios y no puedan entrar por **`url`**.

Trabajo en **`Visual Studio 2008`**

**Aquí mi código:**

```
            Transaccion t = new Transaccion();
            DataSet menu_permisos = new DataSet();
            DataTable pagina_acceso_usuario = new DataTable();
            menu_permisos = t.Mostrar_Menu(usuario.Name);
            pagina_acceso_usuario = menu_permisos.Tables[1];
            string url_pagina = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            url_pagina = url_pagina.Replace("/", "");

            List<string> paginas_guardadas = new List<string>();
            if (pagina_acceso_usuario.Rows.Count != 0)
            {

                foreach (DataRow item in pagina_acceso_usuario.Rows)
                {
                    string nombre_pagina="";
                    nombre_pagina = item[4].ToString();
                    nombre_pagina = nombre_pagina.Replace("/", "");
                    paginas_guardadas.Add(nombre_pagina);
                }

                // Si el usuario introduce la url de una pagina y este se encuentra en la lista lo redirecciona a la pagina.
                bool elemento_lista = paginas_guardadas.Any(x => x == url_pagina);
                if (elemento_lista == true )
                {
                    Response.Redirect("/"+url_pagina, true);
                }

                //Aqui redirecciono si la pagina introducida en la url no se encuentra me redirecciona a default.aspx. Pero aqui se comienza a hacer un ciclo infinito no importa si la pagina esta establecida como de inicio.
                else 
                {
                   Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx",true);

                }


            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Otrapaginaexterna.aspx", true);

            }
```

Comment: Ya validaste  si lo que llega aquí -> `bool elemento_lista` si sea un true ?

Comment: Hola @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO he introducido el nombre de la pagina frmLogistica la cual se encuentra en mis tablas como lo muestro en la imagen y cuando valida entra en el true pero al llegar al response y continua sube nuevamente al principio del código y vuelve za a ejecutarse.

Comment: a ese response no le hace falta la virgulilla **`~`** ?  mejor dicho asi , por que si entra debería de realizar la dirección. `Response.Redirect("~/"+url_pagina, true);`, Has una prueba , quemando la url el en response si te redirecciona estas poniendo mal la url hace falta concatenar un string o algo para que funcione.

Comment: Hola @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO ya se lo he clocado pero no entiendo porque aun me sigue redireccionando es un poco raro. He intentado también con Response.Redirect("~/"+url_pagina, false);  Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();    Pero no ha dado resultado a este bucle infinito sin importar la url. Todo el código anterior  esta dentro de la master page y dento de !IsPostback. Por ultimo intente con form1.Action = "aqui va la url"; y este no me forma bucles pero no se si es una buena practica hacer esto o es correcto.

Comment: Ya quitaste el `else` donde redireccionas a tu pagina `default` a  ver como te funciona  ?

Comment: Hola @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO ya lo he quitado como me recomendaste. He colocado un punto de interrupción y he ejecutado mi código, al llegar a elemento_lista con el valor de true entra y pasa por el Response al seguir ejecutando paso a paso me doy cuenta que este no termina después del Response sube al principio del código para ejecutarse nuevamente y no entiendo porque.

Comment: Sopecho que el error esta en la pagina a donde estas redireccionando , tienes el codigo en una pagina que siempre se ejecuta por eso vuelve a ingresar cuando hace la redireccion

Comment: Sospecho, de  su pagin.aspx la página está enlazada a la misma página principal. Cada vez que el acceso de la pagina de pagina.aspx, se ejecutará el código de redirección en la página principal, lo que resulta en un bucle infinito hasta que algo se agota.

Comment: Hola @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO pues no entiendo a que se debe esto incluso ya comente el código del isPosback a la pagina que se redirecciona que es diferente a la de default y me sigue haciendo el bucle infinito y como comentas termina hasta que algo se agota ya que cuando detengo la ejecución me sale el mensaje  localhost se a redireccionado varias veces. No se como solucionarlo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97730/discussion-between-francisco-j-blanco-and-shinobi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto mi problema modificando un poco el código recordando que default.aspx esta como Establecida de inicio.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
       {
        Transaccion t = new Transaccion();
        DataSet menu_permisos = new DataSet();
        DataTable pagina_acceso_usuario = new DataTable();
        menu_permisos = t.Mostrar_Menu(usuario.Name);
        pagina_acceso_usuario = menu_permisos.Tables[1];
        string url_pagina = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Replace("/", "");;


        List<string> paginas_guardadas = new List<string>();
        if (pagina_acceso_usuario.Rows.Count != 0)
        {

            foreach (DataRow item in pagina_acceso_usuario.Rows)
            {
                string nombre_pagina="";
                nombre_pagina = item[4].ToString();
                nombre_pagina = nombre_pagina.Replace("/", "");
                paginas_guardadas.Add(nombre_pagina);
            }


            bool elemento_lista = paginas_guardadas.Any(x => x == url_pagina);
            if (elemento_lista == true )
            {
               form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
            }

            else 
            {
                if (url_pagina != "default.aspx")
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx", true);                           
                    }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Otrapaginaexterna.aspx", true);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checa por tu flujo en los if, pudiera ser que le falte un `else` a tu segundo if. Sin este, se estarían evaluando las dos condiciones. Intenta con un `if {} else if {} else {}`

```
            if (elemento_lista > 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect(url_pagina, true);
            }
            //Aqui redirecciono si la pagina a cargar es igual a la pagina establecida como inicio pero despues del if vuelve hacia arriba a ejecutar el codigo y no termina el if
            else if (url_pagina == "default.aspx") 
            {
                 Response.Redirect("/" + url_pagina,true);

            }
            //Aqui redirecciono si las dos anteriores no se cumplen
            else 
            {
               Response.Redirect("~/Otrapaginaexterna.aspx");

            }
```

Comment: Hola @kodiakMx ya lo intente como me lo propones. Cambien el segundo if por un else if y después de entrar vuelve a ejecutarse desde el dataset sin pasar por la llave( } ) de finalizacion del else if